# .contains() method throws java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: scala, collections

I am trying to remove given elements for n occurences(not all occurrences!) in the list.
The problem I'm facing is when I try to branch into two cases in which the list contains the given element or does not. My if statement gives me an error as descripted in the title. How can I resolve this problem?

My code

```scala
def removeN[A](xs: List[A], elem: A, n: Int) : List[A] = {
    val elemCount = xs.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)(elem)
    if (xs.contains(elem) == false)
      xs
    else if (elemCount == n) 
      xs.filterNot(x => x == elem)
    else {
      val (left, right) = xs.span(_ != elem)
      print(s"$left and $right")
      left ::: right.tail  
    }
}
```

Error messages

```
    removeN(List(1,2,3,2,1), 0, 2)
    
    java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 0
    at scala.collection.MapOps.default(Map.scala:274)
    at scala.collection.MapOps.default$(Map.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMapView.default(MapView.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.MapOps.apply(Map.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.MapOps.apply$(Map.scala:175)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMapView.apply(MapView.scala:186)
    at removeN(<console>:3)
    ... 32 elided


Test Case
removeN(List(1,2,3,2,1), 0, 2)  // => List(1, 2, 3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: What makes you think `contains` throws it? There is no `contains` on stack ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, I am missing something, but your function (after fixing the bug mentioned in the other answer) seems to be removing all occurrences if there are exactly `n` of them, or *just the first* occurrence otherwise (it is also very inefficient, involving multiple redundant traversals of the list).

Here is a (more efficient) version, removing first N occurrences, assuming that's what you actually were after:

```
def removeN[A](xs: List[A], elem: A, n: Int, result: List[A]=Nil): List[A] = xs match {
    case Nil => result.reverse
    case `elem`::tail if n > 0 => removeN(tail, elem, n-1 result)
    case head::tail => removeN(tail, elem, n, head::result)
 }
```

This can be marginally improved further by adding a "shortcut" special case for `n==0 && result == Nil`, but doesn't seem worth the effort and loss of readability.

Answer (score 5):

It is not `contains` which is throwing - you are trying to get the element from map before checking if it will be there at all:

```
val elemCount = xs.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)(elem)
```

just count elements in-place:

```
def removeN[A](xs: List[A], elem: A, n: Int) : List[A] = {
    if (xs.contains(elem) == false) xs
    else if (xs.count(_ == elem) == n) xs.filterNot(x => x == elem)
    else {
        val (left, right) = xs.span(_ != elem)
        print(s"$left and $right")
        left ::: right.tail  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution is absolutely fine, but I think it's also worth mentioning a couple of alternatives. The first if purely functional but not stack safe, although it ensures that you only traverse the list at most once and immediately terminates when `n` drops to `0`:

```
def removeN[A](xs: List[A], elem: A, n: Int): List[A] =
  xs match {
    case head :: tail if n > 0 =>
      if (head == elem) removeN (tail, elem, n - 1)
      else head :: removeN (tail, elem, n)
    case _ => xs
  }
```

If you are open to using local mutability (while preserving referential transparency) you can also use the following approach:

```
def removeN[A](xs: List[A], elem: A, n: Int): List[A] = {
  var left = n
  var rest = xs
  val result = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[A]
  while (left > 0 && rest != Nil) {
    if (rest.head == elem) {
      left -= 1
    } else {
      result += rest.head
    }
    rest = rest.tail
  }
  rest.foreach(result += _)
  result.toList
}
```

This traverses the list at most once, is stack safe and terminates early if possible.

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/IXDNXrulQYG8eXSzak7UGA).